# Understanding Java modulo?

Tags: java, modulo

I am pretty new to Java. I am having trouble understanding these lines of code. Could someone break it down for me in a basic manner?

Code:

```
private boolean isEven(int even) {
    return even % 2 == 0;
}

private boolean canMove(int roll) {
    int avenues = isEven(this.getStreet()) ? this.getAvenue() : 4 - this
            .getAvenue();
    return this.getStreet() * 5 + avenues + roll < 25;
}
```

Comment: Are you having trouble with the modulus operator or the `canMove` code?

Comment: What is it you do not understand? What have you tried to do to understand it? That kind of questions, especially without any sign of work done, are not usually welcome on SO.

Answer (score 2):

Think of the modulus operator (`%` here in Java) as the "remainder" operator.  It yields the remainder when dividing the first number by the second.

If the remainder when dividing by 2 is zero, then the number is even (`true` returned), else it's odd (`false` returned).

Then the result of the method is used to choose either `this.getAvenue()` or `4 - this.getAvenue()` for the `avenues` variable.

Then avenues is used to compute another sum, which is compared to `25`.  If that sum is less than 25, then `true` is returned; else `false` is returned.

Comment: what about the last line "return this.getStreet() * 5 + avenues + roll < 25;"?

Answer (score 1):

**isEven**:

If the value `even` divided by `2` has no remainder, then return true; else, return false.

**canMove**:

If the current street (`this.getStreet()`) isEven, then use the current Avenue (`this.getAvenue()`); else, use 4 - the current Avenue.  The result of this is stored in `avenues`.

If the current street times 5 + `avenues` + a roll value is less than 25, return true; else return false;

Rewritten, this could be:

```
private boolean canMove(int roll) {
    // create the avenues variable and initialize it with a value
    int avenues = 0;

    // if this.getStreet() is even, then avenues = this.getAvenue()
    if (isEven(this.getStreet()) {
        avenues = this.getAvenue();

    // otherwise, avenues = 4 - this.getAvenue()
    } else {
        avenues = 4 - this.getAvenue();
    }

    // if this.getStreet() * 5 + avenues + roll is less than 25, then return true
    if (this.getStreet() * 5 + avenues + roll < 25) {
        return true;
    }

    // otherwise, return false
    return false;
}
```

Comment: And what does the 4- do, dose it simply takes 4 off of the current avenue?

Comment: @user2472469 It is `4 minus the current Avenue`.  If the current Avenue is `1`, then the equivalent statement would be `4-1`, which is obviously `3`.